# How to add JSON values to an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson

I have the following JSON file:

```json
{
  "meta" : {
    "stock" : "AWS",
    "date modified" : 90
  },
  "roles" : [ "Member", "Admin" ],
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "admin" : true,
  "email" : "john.doe@example.com"
}
```

I wanted to both read the values of the keys and add them to an Array List.

```java
try {
    // create object mapper instance
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // convert JSON file to map
    Map<?, ?> map = mapper.readValue(Paths.get("user.json").toFile(), Map.class);

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    // print map entries
    for (Map.Entry<?, ?> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println((entry.getClass()) + "  " + entry.getValue());
        data.add((String)entry.getValue()); // trying to add entry values to arraylist
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm able to print out the data type of the value along with the value itself. All the values  are part of class `java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry`. I'm not able to cast the values to a `String` to add them to an ArrayList. How should I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: *// convert JSON file to map* - from the json, please tell what the key is and what part is the value?

Comment: @ScaryWombat keys: "meta", "roles", "admin", "email"    values: object of "stock" and "date modified", list containing "member" and "admin", "John Doe", true, and "johndoe@example.com"

Comment: What String value are you expecting to get for "meta" or "roles"?

Comment: @tgdavies {stock=AWS, date modified=90} and [Member, Admin] respectively

Comment: Then you'll need to render your values to Strings, casting doesn't convert non-Strings to Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) documentation you can convert your json to a `Map<String, Object>` *map* with the following line (you have boolean, list, number and string values in your json) :

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
// it prints {meta={stock=AWS, date modified=90}, roles=[Member, Admin], name=John Doe, admin=true, email=john.doe@example.com}
System.out.println(map);
```

If you want to save your *map* values string representation into an `ArrayList` *data* you can iterate over them with a loop :

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object value : map.values()) {
    data.add(value.toString());
}
//it will print [{stock=AWS, date modified=90}, [Member, Admin], John Doe, true, john.doe@example.com]
System.out.println(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data type of entries will be like:

```
meta: Map<String:Object>
roles: List<String>
admin: Boolean
```

So you will get an exception when casting to string for each entry value.
You should handle different data type and convert it according to your request:

```
Object value = entry.getValue();
```

I highly recommend you write more few functions to check and convert map/list/primitive variables to expected data (String):

```
boolean isList(Object obj);
boolean isMap(Object obj);
...
public List<String> convertMap(Map<String,Object> map);
...
```